# How to Fire Drag event from Extjs Grid

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, drag-and-drop, extjs4

How to create HTML Drag event from Extjs Grid and Drop into third party software. This third party software will listen HTML Drop event.

I need set ExtJs Grid selected row data in the Drag event object

```
 Event.dataTransfer.setData("text", "mygridvalue");
```

I searched Extjs documentation for Drag and Drop but ExtJs have their own drag and drop implementation.

I tried to trigger drag event after selecting row in the extjs but no success.

sample grid.
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1m9f&view/editor